# Pippin prep kits - expiration date

Tags: lab-techniques

Do you use Pippin prep? We would like to buy it, but we need more info. What is the **expiration date of kits for Pippin prep**? Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer to ask?

Comment: @Atl LED of course yes, but they dont answer yet. I need this info right now :)

Comment: You tried calling 800-284-8474 and they didn't know off hand?  Ask to speak to tech support if you don't get anywhere else.  Best not to make lab purchases when you have to make a decision in less than half a day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this document](http://www.n-genetics.com/file/Pippin-Prep-Operations-Manual-Rev-6.00-CD6.pdf) (page 11) the shelf life for the cassettes is 1 year. The other ingredients (running buffer, DNA size markers, loading dye) appear to be standard reagents. Of those, the DNA size marker will probably have the shortest shelf life, but it stands to reason that the reagents should have a shelf life at least as long as the cassettes, seeing as only their shelf life is mentioned. It is possible to buy reagent replacement kits.